# there is no sound in laptop speakers in Ubuntu 17.10, but headphones work

Tags: pulseaudio, laptop, alsa, 17.10, speakers

I have a problem for quite a while now, i can't get the sound in my laptop speakers, I've tried everything in the forums but its not working, i have the master volume and speaker volume 100, but no sign of sound, only headphones work.

Comment: Can you add some info / details : version of Ubuntu, Laptop with Sound card, how do you have your settings, what applications are you using... that sort of thing.
Thanks.